# Connection errors when trying to use Memcache

Tags: apache-2.2, php, cache, memcached

I'm new to 'Memcache' but I've installed it and I think its' running, so far have I done the following correct?

```
mkdir memcache
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-3.0.6.tgz
tar -xvfz memcache-3.0.6.tgz
cd memcache-3.0.6
phpize
./configure
make
make install
echo "extension=memcache.so" >> /usr/local/lib/php.ini
service httpd restart
```

However when I try and connect using:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

I'm provided with: `Memcache::connect() [memcache.connect]: Can't connect to localhost:11211, Connection refused (111)`

I've seen people say try and telnet using `telnet localhost 11211` but if I try that I get **Connection Refused**

I've tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 but no luck either.

Have I installed the wrong memcache? If so how can I remove the one I have just added? or is that I needed libevent?

Comment: Dumb question, but is the `memcached` daemon running?  Try running a `netstat -lntp` and looking for 11211.  You can also run `ps -axw | grep [m]emcached`, if you get nothing you need to start the `memcached` daemon.

Comment: @d34dh0r53 no it's not there, but when I type memcached I just get `command not found`

Answer (score 3):

I'm putting this in an answer now as I think I know your problem.  You have only installed the PECL module for memcached which is essentially a client library and not the actual memcache server.  You need to download and install the latest memcached daemon from here:

[http://memcached.org](http://memcached.org/)

Once you have that installed you'll be able to start the daemon and connect to port 11211.  As an aside, depending on the distribution you're running there may be a memcached package available to you in your repositories.  I would highly recommend you install this package instead of rolling your own memcached as it will greatly simplify upgrading and managing memcached.

Comment: thanks, do I need to remove what I installed previously?

Comment: No, once you have the daemon installed you will use the PECL module to connect to it via PHP.